# "Object does not contain a definition for "LoadFile" C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and am translating vb.net to C# on Visual Studio and I have this line of code where it tells me,

"'Object' does not contain a definition for 'LoadFile' and no accessible extension method 'LoadFile' accpeting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
wia.LoadFile(imagefile);
```

I can post more details of the code, I have added a reference for WIA but I feel like either the object is created incorrectly or I'm missing a reference. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `wia`?  What is `imageFile`?  Why do you expect `wia` to have a method called `LoadFile` which accepts the `imageFile` instance?

Comment: Depending on the `Option`s in the original code, VB.NET can treat `Object` the way C# does `dynamic` (with some nuanced difference). That's probably why it worked in VB.NET using `Object` and not in C# with `object`/`Object`.